# webshere snap files - What is it

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

I have recently enabled java heap dumps and java thread dumps/javacore files on my websphere server v6.1. here is an example of the files that get created on my server.

javacore.20150728.142732.7726.txt
heapdump.20150728.142732.7726.phd

But I am also seeing some snap files. For example:

Snap0001.20150725.074003.29341.trc

What is the snap file and how does it differ from the other two.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javacore` is a thread dump, shows state of threads in the application server.
`heapdump` is memory dump, shows objects allocated in the JVM heap.
`snap` contain the tracepoint data held in the trace buffers. For more details see - [Snap traces](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/tools/dumpagents_snaptrace.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F9-3-8-2-2-1-6&lang=en)

Comment: Thanks. Are snap traces useful for debugging application issues or are they more of an internal thing. Sorry to ask it's just that the explanation given for them at the link is that it's trace point data for buffers.. But I don't get what that means?

Comment: @Richie To be honest I didn't ever need to look in them, so I'd say they are more for IBM support.